# secure asp.net web-site via another application located on another server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, license-key

I have distributed asp.net web-site. This applications was installed on customers servers. I want to license this application, and if license period elapsed to block customer application. Require a method of protecting a permit application from another server. 
For example, include in web-config encrypted data, that use application on another server, that will give rights to run application on distribution server. May be it done, if server rebooted, to initialize application by passing some masterKey Data.
Have some Idea, or practices?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered WCF, perhaps?

Comment: I want to control licensing of applications that installed on customers servers.

Comment: I've read about LicenseProvider class. But I'm not sure are there some alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You could have a crypt key stored in a file along side with the application. If the file is missing and or the key isn't valid then don't let the application run on the server.

The key could contain date and server s/n to make sure the key only is valid for a limited time and the s/n to make sure the file isn't copied to another server.

To ask another server over TCP is to me bad practice since all your customers will be dependent on your server being online 100%.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but I want to use main License Provider Server, and we will grant 100% internet access all time.

Comment: Then you could download the same type of key from the "main License Provider Server". Just make sure the key and or the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: Send your customers servers s/n or some kind of license key encrypted to you license server and if they have a valid license, return a key that is valid during an limited time (to force the application to call for a new one later). Else just return false/null/nothing and your asp.net site should know not to run.